# Отступ у div, изменяющийся при изменении размера экрана

Tags: css3, html5

Имеется такой код с SO:

```css
.shapka {
  background: #e73c3c;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: flex;
}

.cat {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.cat div {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1; // дает приоритет на растяжение блока
}

.search input {
  flex-grow: 1; // дает приоритет на растяжение блока
  line-height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.search button {
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapka">
  <div class="cat">
    <div>Каталог товаров</div>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <input id="oem" name="oem" placeholder="Поиск" type="text"><button type="submit">Найти</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать в таком коде, что бы эти элементы при изменении размера экрана растягивались до какого то значения, а после они не изменялись, а появлялись бы отступы слева и справа экрана.
P.S.: на этом сайте так сделано в шапке с поиском. Примерно до 1000px растягивается строка поиска, а дальше размер не изменяется увеличивается только отступ слева и справа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.shapka {
  ...
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Смотрите сниппет в развернутом виде

```css
.shapka {
  background: #e73c3c;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cat {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.cat div {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1; // дает приоритет на растяжение блока
}

.search input {
  flex-grow: 1; // дает приоритет на растяжение блока
  line-height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.search button {
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapka">
  <div class="cat">
    <div>Каталог товаров</div>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <input id="oem" name="oem" placeholder="Поиск" type="text"><button type="submit">Найти</button>
  </div>
</div>
```